# Multiple Conditional Joins

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-query-builder

I tried using multiple conditionals in my JOIN but Laravel assumes that on JOIN I'll be comparing my fields and not a constant value. Do I have to wrap this in a `raw()` method and then escape it using `DB::connection()->getPdo()->quote()` or are there any shortcuts to this?

```
->join('tags', function($join) use ($tags) {
    $join->on('tags.id', '=', 'resource_tag.tag_id');
    $join->on('tags.name', '=', $tags);
})

->join('tags', function($join) use ($tags) {
    $join->on('tags.id', '=', 'resource_tag.tag_id');
    $join->on('tags.name', '=', DB::raw(DB::connection()->getPdo()->quote($tags)));
})
```

This seemed to work but seemed a bit much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's not a field you have to use `DB::raw`.

You can shorten your code a little bit by removed the `connection()` method. You don't need that as your already on the default connection.

```
DB::raw(DB::getPdo()->quote($tags))
```

If you don't want to use `DB::raw`, you can use a 
`where` statement (outside of your `join` method).

```
where('tags.name', $tags)
```

```
Model::join('tags', 'tags.id', '=', 'resource_tag.tag_id')->where('tags.name', $tags)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Yea, I thought I was out of luck. Really surprised that these orms and query builders have been out for so long yet stuff hasn't been built in yet. Regarding the where, yes that is true however, that would defeat the purposes of me optimizing my query haha.  If i were to do that, the join would be much larger and then filtered.  I've done explain on both and the way i'm doing it appears to be more efficient.